# How to update array of objects in react native useState inside for loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, state

I have a state containing array of objects that I want to update my object inside for loop.
Here is my codes:
Each objects contain value, text and time. The **time** should update inside for loop.

```
const [initialValues, setInitialValue] = useState([
        {
            value: 128,
            text: '128 Kb',
            time: ''
        },
        {
            value: 256,
            text: '256 Kb',
            time: ''
        },
        {
            value: 512,
            text: '512 Kb',
            time: ''
        },
        {
            value: 750,
            text: '750 Kb',
            time: ''
        },
        {
            value: 1024,
            text: '1 MB',
            time: ''
        },
        {
            value: 2048,
            text: '2 MB',
            time: ''
        },
        {
            value: 3072,
            text: '3 MB',
            time: ''
        },
        {
            value: 4096,
            text: '4 MB',
            time: ''
        },
        {
            value: 5120,
            text: '5 MB',
            time: ''
        }
    ]);
```

The for loop where I want to update my state:
The calculate is a function that will be called on **onPress** event from user side.

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState('1')
const [data, setData] = useState('1024')
const calculate = () => {
        if (number) {

            let size = number * data * 8
            size = percentage(12, size) + size;

            for (let value of initialValues) {
                let data = value.value;
                data = (size / data).toFixed();
                // here is my approach but not correct
                setInitialValue({ ...initialValues, time: data })

            }
        }
    }
```

But the result is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your calculate function to this

```
const calculate = () => {
if (number) {
    let size = number * data * 8;
    size = percentage(12, size) + size;
    const newValues = [...initialValues.slice()];

    for (let i = 0; i < newValues.length; i++) {
        let data = (size / data).toFixed();
        newValues[i].time = data;
    }

    setInitialValue(newValues);
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

store initial value in a variable and pass it to the useState like this

```
const [initialValues, setInitialValue] = useState(initialVaule);
const [number, setNumber] = useState(1)
const [data, setData] = useState(1024)

const calculate = () => {
        if (number && data) {

            let size = number * data * 8
            size = percentage(12, size) + size;

           let updatedValue = intialValues.map( item => {
              return item.time = (size / data).toFixed();
           })
           setInitialValue(updatedValue);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't be assigning `item.time = (size / data).toFixed()` to `initialValues` when `initialValues` is an array